# Inverse of constant matrix plus diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there an efficient way to calculate the inverse of an $N \times N$ diagonal matrix plus a constant matrix? I am looking at $N$ of around $40,000$.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a & b & \cdots & b\\
b & a &  & \vdots\\
\vdots &  & \ddots & b\\
b & \cdots & b & a
\end{array}\right]^{-1} = \,\,?$$

Putting this in to mathematica, for $N \in \{2, 3, 4\}$, the result is:

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 b & a \\
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a}{a^2-b^2} & -\frac{b}{a^2-b^2} \\
 -\frac{b}{a^2-b^2} & \frac{a}{a^2-b^2} \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & b \\
 b & a & b \\
 b & b & a \\
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} & \frac{-a b+b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} & \frac{-a b+b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} \\
 \frac{-a b+b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} & \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} & \frac{-a b+b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} \\
 \frac{-a b+b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} & \frac{-a b+b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} & \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3} \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & b & b & b \\
 b & a & b & b \\
 b & b & a & b \\
 b & b & b & a \\
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6
a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} \\
 \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6
a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} \\
 \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3}{a^4-6
a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} \\
 \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{-a^2 b+2 a b^2-b^3}{a^4-6
a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} & \frac{a^3-3 a b^2+2 b^3}{a^4-6 a^2 b^2+8 a b^3-3 b^4} \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

It appears that there should be a formula but I am not sure how to derive it. In the end, I am looking for a numerical result.

Comment: I think it's important to notice that we must have $a \neq b$, otherwise the inverse won't exist.

Comment: Yes, and $a$ can't be $-(n - 1)b$ either (for then every row sum (or column sum) will be $0$, so that the matrix is singular).

Comment: It reminds me of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778455/invert-a-matrix/778512).

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931703/detd-c-where-d-is-diagonal-and-c-is-a-constant-matrix-all-entries-e

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

$$
\textbf{P} =
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Note that

$$
\textbf{P}^2 = n \textbf{P}
$$

You want the inverse of

$$
b \textbf{P} + (a-b) \textbf{I}
$$

You can try

$$
k \textbf{P} + \frac{1}{a-b} \textbf{I}
$$

So

$$
\Big( b \textbf{P} + (a-b) \textbf{I} \Big) \Big( k \textbf{P} + \frac{1}{a-b} \textbf{I} \Big) = \textbf{I}
$$

Then we get

$$
\Big( nbk + (a-b)k + \frac{b}{a-b}\Big) \textbf{P} + \textbf{I} = \textbf{I}
$$

so you can solve $k$ and you find

$$ 
k = \frac{-b}{(a-b)(nb+a-b)}
$$

So you would get

$$
\Big( b \textbf{P} + (a-b) \textbf{I} \Big)^{-1}  =  \frac{-b}{(a-b)(nb+a-b)} \textbf{P} + \frac{1}{a-b} \textbf{I} {}{}{}
$$

Comment: Can a similar result be derived for a diagonal matrix with different diagonal entries?

Comment: what @aaronqli asked

Answer (score 9):

I believe you can obtain the inverse using the Sherman-Morrison formula,

namely

$(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - {A^{-1}uv^T A^{-1} \over 1 + v^T A^{-1}u}$.

[See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula ]

Choosing

$$
u = v = \sqrt{b}[\begin{array} 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{array}]^T,
$$
and
$$
A = (a-b)I
$$
yields a matrix of the correct form, i.e.
$$
(A+uv^T) = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} a & b & \cdots & b\\
b & a & & \vdots\\
\vdots & &\ddots &b\\
b & \cdots & b & a
 \end{array}\right].
$$

The inverse is then obtained from a straightforward application of the formula.

The nice thing about obtaining the inverse using the Sherman Morrison formula is that it generalizes to an arbitrary invertible matrix $A$, not just a multiple of the identity.  The only restriction is that $1+v^TA^{-1}u \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the result is well-known. Yet, using a software as mathematica, we can easily guess the correct formula. To do that, you must ask mathematica to factorize. For instance, let $n=4$ ; if $i\not=j$, then $factor((A^{-1})_{i,j})=\dfrac{-b}{(a-b)(3b+a)}$ and  $factor((A^{-1})_{i,i})=\dfrac{2b+a}{(a-b)(3b+a)}$. With few values of $n$, I obtain (unless I am not good for mathematics) ${A^{-1}}_{i,j}=\dfrac{-b}{(a-b)(nb+a-b)}$ and ${A^{-1}}_{i,i}=\dfrac{nb+a-2b}{(a-b)(nb+a-b)}$. Then, it is necessary to prove that this result is correct ; yet, the work is easier when we know (before) the formula.