# Finding a generalized form for the inverse of a matrix with changing $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ square matrix such that
$$
a_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
 2 &\text{if}\, i=j \\ 
 -1 &\text{if}\, i\neq j,
\end{cases}
$$
where $a_{ij}$ represents the entry in the $i$th row and $j$th column of $A$. I would like to get a generalized form of the inverse of this matrix given $n>1$.

I have noticed that the inverse exists for all $n$ except when $n=3$. I have computed the inverse until $n=8$ and observed that the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ is given by
\begin{align}
a^{-1}_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{n-4}{3(n-3)} &\text{if}\, i=j \\ 
 \frac{-1}{3(n-3)} &\text{if}\, i\ne j.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
For instance, for $n=2$, we have
$$ A^{-1} = 
\left( \begin{matrix} 
2/3 & 1/3\\ 
 1/3 & 2/3
\end{matrix} \right) 
$$
and for $n=4$, we have
$$ A^{-1} = 
\left( \begin{matrix} 
0 & -1/3 & -1/3 & -1/3\\ 
-1/3 & 0 & -1/3 & -1/3\\
-1/3 & -1/3 & 0 & -1/3\\
-1/3 & -1/3 & -1/3 &0
\end{matrix} \right) .
$$
As mentioned above, I have observed the inverse until $n=8$ and this seems to be the trend for all $n$, except $n=3.$ However, I couldn't find a formal way to show this mathematically. Can someone offer me guidance on how to show that the inverse exists if $n\ne 3$ and that $A^{-1}$ is indeed given by
$$
a^{-1}_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{n-4}{3(n-3)} &\text{if}\, i=j \\ 
 \frac{-1}{3(n-3)} &\text{if}\, i\ne j
\end{cases}
$$
if this is true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determinant of a specially structured matrix ($a$'s on the diagonal, all other entries equal to $b$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix-as-on-the-diagonal-all-other-e) and [Show that the matrix with a's on the diagonal and b's off the diagonal has got an inverse with the same structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2769956/show-that-the-matrix-with-as-on-the-diagonal-and-bs-off-the-diagonal-has-got-a).

Comment: Aha. I knew I had seen a variant of this before. Good catch!

Comment: Great, thank you! @DietrichBurde